# Dynamically set text on input submit button with Angular

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="submit" value="Create new order" />
```

How do I set the 'value' attribute based on a $scope variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/DZWzN4D9QzzBCpetSYtF?p=preview

```
<input type="submit" value="{{model}}" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.model = "Create new order";
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="{{scopeVar}}" />

$scope.scopeVar = "some value";
```